# Задача на ветвление

Tags: javascript

Начал проходить первый [курс](http://www.codecademy.com), но в конце столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу закончить. В чем проблема? Что неправильно написал?

```
var myName = "Ololoshechka"; 
if (myName.length === 12)
{
    console.log("Первый курс завершён!");
}
else {
    console.log("Не завершен");
}
```

Вот сама задача:

> Напишите свою собственную конструкцию if / else.
> Результатом проверки условия должен быть вывод на экран фразы "Первый курс завершён!".

Comment: Да, и впрямь урок бажный.

Comment: Т.е. я все правильно написал?

Comment: @Сяськаа Ну, в общем, тут не очень сложно :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да ну ладно... )) Учится человек. 

@Сяськаа, если не срабатывает, то возможно условие задачи не так поняли. Я б глянул, но только чего-то мне облом проходить весь курс ;)

Comment: Да вот если бы не так понял)
1) Напишите свою собственную конструкцию if / else. 
2) Результатом проверки условия должен быть вывод на экран фразы "Первый курс завершён!

Разве тут не так поймешь?)

Comment: Заинтриговали, а ссылочку на задачу кинуть не желаете. Хотите заставить стричка через все круги "Hello, Word!" пройти? ))

Comment: С удовольствием дал бы линк на задачку,только проблема в том,чтобы попасть на эту задачку нужно предыдущие пройти)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно написано, и конструкция if else - работает.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Так ведь всё работает.
Возможно, под выводом "на экран" понимается отображение модального окошка — тогда используйте `alert` вместо `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего - вывод на экран это:

```
document.write("Первый курс завершён!");
```

Или

```
document.writeln("Первый курс завершён!");
```

Comment: Не подходит. Как я понял,это что-то вроде экз.вопроса по пройденному материалу. 
Проходилось там только alert (не подходит) и console.log

Answer (score -3):

if (myName.length === 12)
должно ж быть "==", а не "==="
я в джаву вообще никак, но в шарпе было бы так

Comment: >я в джаву вообще никак

Может с этого стоило начинать?

Comment: В js есть такой оператор как [строгое равенство](http://learn.javascript.ru/comparison-operators#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Comment: я советую вам выучить c# хотя бы основы для начала, а потом говорить